# Where is the "Legacy Mesh Format" option im the Save As dialog?

Tags: mesh, export

I need to use the "Legacy Mesh Format" option to be able to export Blender meshes. In 2.79 this is available when selecting "Save As", but I cannot find it in 2.82.

Is it somewhere else, or, if not, is it possible to work around this somehow? Right now, I have to first append the mesh to a 2.79 file, resave it as Legacy Mesh Format, and then use the 2.79 file for further processing, which is annoying.

I can of course stick with 2.79, but I much prefer the new user interface, so I would like to be able to solve this.

Thanks, PSD